# Best Networking File Share Software

Tags: networking

I currently use Samba between my Ubuntu machine, Debian machine, and Raspberry Pi's. Due to reports of Samba being nutorious for spiking the CPU on the Pi stack exchange, I am wondering what alternative file sharing software I can use that will also be compatible with my other machines? If possible, please tell me what might be best and why.

Comment: "Best" is a matter of opinion. By the way: samba is for sharing with Windows. Otherwise I would opt for "nfs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo) is designed for sharing files between Linux machines and is much kinder to CPUs, it just can't support windows as far as I know.

The following info is taken from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/network-file-system.html)

**Installation**

At a terminal prompt enter the following command to install the NFS Server:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
```

**Configuration**

You can configure the directories to be exported by adding them to the /etc/exports file. For example:

```
/ubuntu  *(ro,sync,no_root_squash)
/home    *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

You can replace * with one of the hostname formats. Make the hostname declaration as specific as possible so unwanted systems cannot access the NFS mount.

To start the NFS server, you can run the following command at a terminal prompt:

```
sudo service nfs-kernel-server start
```

**NFS Client Configuration**

Use the mount command to mount a shared NFS directory from another machine, by typing a command line similar to the following at a terminal prompt:

```
sudo mount example.hostname.com:/ubuntu /local/ubuntu
```

The mount point directory /local/ubuntu must exist. There should be no files or subdirectories in the /local/ubuntu directory.

An alternate way to mount an NFS share from another machine is to add a line to the /etc/fstab file. The line must state the hostname of the NFS server, the directory on the server being exported, and the directory on the local machine where the NFS share is to be mounted.

The general syntax for the line in `/etc/fstab` file is as follows:

```
example.hostname.com:/ubuntu /local/ubuntu nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
```

If you have trouble mounting an NFS share, make sure the nfs-common package is installed on your client. To install nfs-common enter the following command at the terminal prompt:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Filezilla its preety good, it's UI is very intuitive and easy to navigate. From command line you can use `scp` command to transfer files. `rsync` is good for synchronizing files between two machines.

Answer (score 1):

NFS is what you are looking for.

> [Source NFS (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System)
>   Network File System (NFS) is a distributed file system protocol originally developed by Sun Microsystems in 1984,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) allowing a user on a client computer to access files over a network much like local storage is accessed. NFS, like many other protocols, builds on the Open Network Computing Remote Procedure Call (ONC RPC) system. The Network File System is an open standard defined in RFCs, allowing anyone to implement the protocol.

To install NFS run:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
```

Then you can add your network shares in `/etc/exports` such as:

```
/ubuntu  *(ro,sync,no_root_squash)
/home    *(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
```

Then restart the server to add the new network shares with:

```
sudo service nfs-kernel-server start
```

With the NFS server setup you can connect to the shares on your client machines using:

```
sudo mount example.hostname.com:/ubuntu /mnt/ubuntu
```

With `example.hostname.com:/ubuntu` being the address of the server and file path and `/mnt/ubuntu` being the mount point on the client machine.

Additionally you can add NFS to your `/etc/fstab` so that the filesystem is mount during bootup. To do this run `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and add the following to the file:

```
example.hostname.com:/ubuntu /mnt/ubuntu nfs rsize=8192, wsize=8192, timeo=14, intr
```

The advantage of this approach over Samba is that NFS is native to Unix and seamlessly adds the share to a path on your filesystem.

Source: [Network File System (NFS)](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-file-system.html)

Comment: Snap! Though you were just that bit quicker!

Comment: At least we have two really good answers on NFS :)